# Facebook Graph API private_replies returning error 10903 This user cant reply to this activity

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot

I am attempting to write an App that sends a message with private_replies, but it always returns the following error:

```
{
  message: '(#10903) This user cant reply to this activity',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 10903,
  fbtrace_id: 'HUzYz7nKBPV'
}
```

I have read a number of solutions, but none seem to be working for me, so I'm not sure if I've missed something or if the something on the Facebook API side has changed.

The App I am creating (currently based on a number of tutorials) waits for a user to mention a specific word in a comment on my page and will then send a message to the user via private_replies.

When I debug my Apps Page Access Token, I get this info:

```
Access Token Info
App ID  18**********164 : MTestChatBot
Type    Page
Page ID 25**********999 : MTestPage
App-Scoped User ID
Learn More
10**********048 : <MY NAME>
User last installed this app via API N/A
Issued  1520423580 (on Wednesday)
Expires Never
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  manage_pages, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, public_profile
```

One of the 'solutions' I have read states that I need to have to App reviewed by Facebook first to get the read_page_mailboxes subscription, but as shown above, I should already have that permission. It also seems odd to get an App reviewed before I can test it.

I have tried giving a friend developer access to the App and Admin rights to the page. When they post comments I get the same error.

I have tried Publishing the page and all comments still get the same result.

In case it's of any use, here is a rough version of the App code:

```
'use strict';

const FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
const FB_VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.FB_VERIFY_TOKEN;

const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const app = express().use(body_parser.json());

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {  
  // Parse params from the webhook verification request
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];

  // Check if a token and mode were sent
  if (mode && token) {  
    // Check the mode and token sent are correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === FB_VERIFY_TOKEN) {      
      // Respond with 200 OK and challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);    
    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);     
    }
  }
});

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  
  // Parse the request body from the POST
  let data = req.body;

  if (data.object === 'page') {
    data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry) {
      var pageID = pageEntry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = pageEntry.time;

      if (pageEntry.hasOwnProperty('changes')) {
        pageEntry.changes.forEach(function(changes){
          if(changes.field === 'feed' && changes.value.item === 'comment' && changes.value.verb === 'add'){
            var messageData = {
              message: 'Hello'
            };
            privateReply(messageData, changes.value.comment_id);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
})

function privateReply(messageData, comment_id) {
    request({
        uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/' + comment_id + '/private_replies',
        qs: { access_token: FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
        method: 'POST',
        json: messageData
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        } else {
            console.error('Private Replies Failed: ', response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
        }
    });  
}
```

All advice gratefully received.

Comment: "Having" a permission on your access token as a user with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) has nothing to do with review - those roles explicitly can be asked for and grant permissions _before_ review, so that you can develop and test your app. Try to reply to a user account that also has a role in your app.

Comment: I did try getting a friend setup up as a developer of the app (also had to be admin of the page to be able to access it) and got them to comment. The same error occured. Also, the token shown is the one the app uses when making API calls. Should I be getting permissions for my App in a different way?

Comment: I get this too sometimes - maybe 1 in 50k or so.

Comment: I get this error when  I try to reply  to a comment written by the page

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a facebook glitch or something. But the user is somehow blocked from receiving private reply from your page